# Set Dropdown's selected values in each row in a table on edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an editable table, where each row have dropdownlist to update the row value. How do I set the dropdownlist selected value on page load for rows on edit page.

My html code:

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("TeamA", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "teamA_" + item.ScheduleID, @class="form-control" })
        </td>
        <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("TeamB", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "teamB_" + item.ScheduleID, @class = "form-control"})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Filling table options through ViewBag.TeamA and ViewBag.TeamB respectively as below

```
ViewBag.TeamA = new SelectList(db.Teams.Where(s => s.RoleID == Id).ToList(), "TeamID", "Name");
ViewBag.TeamB = new SelectList(db.Teams.Where(s => s.RoleID == Id).ToList(), "TeamID", "Name");
```

Comment: Can you share the server side code, so we can know how are you getting the data for the dropdownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your precious time, I solved it by following way.

```
 <td>
    <select name="TeamA" >
        <option value="0">--select--</option>
        @foreach (Team t in ViewBag.TeamA)
        {
            <option value="@t.TeamID" @(t.TeamID == item.Team1 ? "selected" : "")>@t.Name</option>
        }
    </select>                                                
</td>
```

and on server side

```
ViewBag.TeamA = db.Teams.Where(s => s.SeriesID == Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Html in such conditions where you not sure how to do in razor, like in this case use Html dropdown with loop.
e.g.

```
<select>        
        @foreach (var v in ViewBag.DropdownData)
        {
            <option value="@v.ID" @(v.ID == item.DDLID ? "selected" : "")>@v.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the list for the `DorpDownList` and in that you need to define the selected item like below.

```
@Html.DropDownList("TeamA", new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem {  Text = "P1", Value = "1"}, new SelectListItem { Text = "P2", Value = "2", Selected = true} }, "--Select--", new { value = "2"})
```

Please note that I have generated the list (new List) just for example.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `string.optionLabel` in `@Html.DropDownList` to `item.Name` might work, assuming you're using your teams as the Model on the view.

```
@Html.DropDownList("TeamA", null, item.Name, new {@id = "teamA_" + item.ScheduleID, @class="form-control"})
```

This should display correct values if they have any, otherwise it'll be empty.